# What does "Why you should speak English like you’re playing a video game" sentence mean?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I saw this video title on the youtube and i wonder what does it mean.

Does it have same meaning in the sentence "This is why you should speak English..."

or Is "Why should you speak English ..." being tried to tell in video's title?

I noticed this issue on a few video titles, please reply the native speakers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of construction is quite common in titles.

It means "The reason why ... " or "This is why ... "

Comment: Thank for your answer but can you give some examples for being permanent

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, no. The video is not about why you should learn english. The video is about the approach or techniques to learn english.

Specifically in your case, the video is geared towards non-english speaking gamers and informs the viewer that techniques and skills learned in playing video games can also be used to learn english more effectively.

That's what I understood from your quote as a native english speaker.

Comment: I didn't ask the content of video if my question was misunderstood I'm sorry,I can understand more or less what they told in a video. I wanted to ask only whether the video's title is grammatically correct or not.Another example: (I'll give an example name of a TV series)There is no "Did" tag in the sentence "How i met your mother", then I think,This sentence is not a question.It's only a short version of "My way how i met your mother ..." Am I right?